# Отправляю POST запрос по гайду, он выдает ошибку 404 не найденно

Tags: c#, post, httpclient

Я пользуюсь httpclient, для отправки пост запроса. Пост запрос, который я отправляю - это клик, для прогрузки js(текста). Все сделал по гайду https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient , отловил спомощью Fiddler запрос, но он не отправляется. Когда запрос не в виде json, то все нормально работает.
Bот код:

```
string loginURI = "https://www.coursera.org/lecture/golang-webservices-1/tiestirovaniie-http-zaprosov-i-otvietov-U7Cok";

   HttpContent content = new StringContent(
           "{\"clientType\":\"web\",\"app\":\"phoenix\",\"clientVersion\":\"244fb5ab4a0f49e801cd4145742447606f01c256\",\"events\":[{\"key\":\"video_logged_out_page.video_lecture_landing_page.click.expand_description\",\"value\":{\"namespace\":{\"app\":\"video_logged_out_page\",\"page\":\"video_lecture_landing_page\",\"action\":\"click\",\"component\":\"expand_description\"},\"href\":\"#\",\"schema_type\":\"FRONTEND\",\"appName\":\"video-logged-out-page\"},\"clientType\":\"web\",\"url\":\"https://www.coursera.org/lecture/golang-webservices-1/tiestirovaniie-http-zaprosov-i-otvietov-U7Cok\",\"app\":\"phoenix\",\"guid\":\"6d0e2e14-9528-4d5e-e854-e0497f8e8f67\",\"visitId\":\"c7371f58-e972-43cd-e3a2-9ca6b4155d8a\",\"screenSize\":{\"height\":768,\"width\":1366},\"clientVersion\":\"244fb5ab4a0f49e801cd4145742447606f01c256\",\"clientTimestamp\":1585239979060,\"sequence\":35}]}",
           UnicodeEncoding.UTF8,
           "application/json");

   var client = new HttpClient();

   HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync(
   loginURI,
   content);
```

Вот что дает мне Fiddler

```
POST https://www.coursera.org/eventing/infoBatch.v2 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.coursera.org
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 784
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Origin: https://www.coursera.org
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: https://www.coursera.org/lecture/golang-webservices-1/tiestirovaniie-http-zaprosov-i-otvietov-U7Cok
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: CSRF3-Token=1586088427.oAW48unzlmgeEnqb; __204u=9387568943-1585224427908; __204r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F; _ga=GA1.2.410652331.1585224435; _gid=GA1.2.1640748347.1585224435; muxData=mux_viewer_id=fbe71d39-3a56-4277-b9fa-434eaef8b0d7&msn=0.6628066336554108; _fbp=fb.1.1585224442413.1140338668; __400v=c7371f58-e972-43cd-e3a2-9ca6b4155d8a; stc113717=env:1585239904%7C20200426162504%7C20200326165504%7C1%7C1030880:20210326162504|uid:1585224439037.1400077007.3554602.113717.258140911.:20210326162504|srchist:1030879%3A1%3A20200426120719%7C1030880%3A1585239904%3A20200426162504:20210326162504|tsa:1585239904171.302064844.1203208.3423755605444414.1:20200326165504; _tq_id.TV-63455409-1.39ed=1bfb2106d8878fbe.1585224439.0.1585239906..; maId={"cid":"288a074b8811082b3ef43d8e1ff0d6cd","sid":"7643c15b-651e-4758-b630-51e9a3f3f7a9","isSidSaved":true,"sessionStart":"2020-03-26T16:25:03.000Z"}; __400vt=1585239979060

{"clientType":"web","app":"phoenix","clientVersion":"244fb5ab4a0f49e801cd4145742447606f01c256","events":[{"key":"video_logged_out_page.video_lecture_landing_page.click.expand_description","value":{"namespace":{"app":"video_logged_out_page","page":"video_lecture_landing_page","action":"click","component":"expand_description"},"href":"#","schema_type":"FRONTEND","appName":"video-logged-out-page"},"clientType":"web","url":"https://www.coursera.org/lecture/golang-webservices-1/tiestirovaniie-http-zaprosov-i-otvietov-U7Cok","app":"phoenix","guid":"6d0e2e14-9528-4d5e-e854-e0497f8e8f67","visitId":"c7371f58-e972-43cd-e3a2-9ca6b4155d8a","screenSize":{"height":768,"width":1366},"clientVersion":"244fb5ab4a0f49e801cd4145742447606f01c256","clientTimestamp":1585239979060,"sequence":35}]}
```

Вот что я получаю в консоли

```
NotFound     |||      StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2020 16:28:28 GMT
  X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
  Via: 1.1 f0bf906df7f99fe49b4582e655d2c569.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
  X-Amz-Cf-Pop: LHR52-C1
  X-Amz-Cf-Id: VdUj_mZem5UzfNeUkx4pk5uX0O5XXarqaoGFKtGXRXMw-EozkJwfCg==
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 20245
}
```

Comment: `POST https://www.coursera.org/eventing/infoBatch.v2` и значение в `string loginURI` хоть немного похожи по вашему?

Comment: Спасибо, пздц я тупые ошибки делаю, не проверив всего, сорри